# LocalStorage как сохранить переменную которая изменяется

Tags: javascript

У меня есть игра кликер. Мне надо чтобы после перезагрузки страницы счетчик не сбрасывался. Не получается сделать через LocalStorage , точнее получается,после обновление страницы появляется число которое было до обновления,но при нажатия кнопки счетчик становится на 0
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй вот это, надеюсь тебе поможет)

P.S: тут localStorage не работает

```js
let clickBlock = document.querySelector('.clicker');
let scoreBlock = document.querySelector('.score');

let clickCount = localStorage.getItem('clicker-count');
clickCount = clickCount == null ? 0 : clickCount;

scoreBlock.innerHTML = clickCount;


clickBlock.addEventListener('click', () => {
  clickCount++;
  scoreBlock.innerHTML = clickCount;
  localStorage.setItem('clicker-count', clickCount);
})
```

```css
.clicker {
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: royalblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: consolas;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="score">0</div>
<div class="clicker">Click</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло

Comment: @Venom  а можно галочку на вопрос? ^-^

Comment: что за галочка?)